# Javascript Append New onClick Item Malformed

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm having trouble with something that seems like it should be straightforward. After a certain click event, I want something like this to happen:

```
var varOne = 1;
var varTwo = 2;
var varThree = 3;

var data = "<a href='#' onClick='myFunction('"+varOne+"', '"+varTwo+"', '"+varThree+"')'>";
$("#location").append(data);
```

Basically, I should end up with a link with an onclick that looks like:

```
myFunction('1', '2', '3')
```

What I'm getting is one that looks like this:

```
myFunction(" 1',="" '2',="" '3'=""
```

Am I able to do what I'm trying to do? I think it's just an issue with mixing and escaping quotes, but I've spent a few hours stuck on this and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, you're missing a closing bracket and a closing apostrophe, also your `myFunction` should be in double quotes(`"`) instead of single quotes and you have to escape them with a backslash

```js
var varOne = 1;
var varTwo = 2;
var varThree = 3;

var data = "<a href='#' onClick=\"myFunction('"+varOne+"', '"+varTwo+"', '"+varThree+"')\">";
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working. I had a few iterations of this and ultimately it looks like I misunderstood escaping double quotes, then I made some errors on top of that. I'll read up more on how this works before proceeding. Thanks again.